Updating DOCX version using VBA in Microsoft Word
When exporting PDFs to DOCX in Adobe Acrobat, files are saved in an older version (2010?), which lacks support for the latest Word features. The only way to upgrade to the latest version is through the 'Save As' menu in Word, unchecking the option to maintain backward compatibility (using 'Save' alone does not update it). I’d like to automate this process with a macro that saves all open DOCX files and updates them to the latest DOCX version (2016?).
I tried the following code but it does not work, the documents are saved but not updated:
Sub SaveAllDOCXToLastVersion()
    Dim doc As Document
    For Each doc In Application.Documents
        Dim newName As String
        newName = doc.Path & "\" & Replace(doc.Name, ".", "_") & ".docx"
        doc.SaveAs2 FileName:=newName, FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument
    Next doc
    MsgBox "OK!"
End Sub

Is there any way to specify from VBA the version of DOCx to save, or if not, any alternative way to achieve what I am looking for?

See CompatibiltyMode parameter under https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.saveas2

Well, I feel a little dumb now. I had tried using the CompatibilityMode parameter but with the value 0, and it hadn't worked. Checking the link you provided, I changed it to the value 15 and now it works perfectly. Thank you very much!

15 is for Word 2013. 16 is the latest I believe.

You can use a tool like DocTo to achive this.  Full Disclosure I am the author of DocTo.
You can convert all the word documents in a directory to the latest version of word. by using a command like this.

docto -f "C:\Folder\With\OldFiles" -O "C:\Folder\For\NewFiles"
-T wdFormatDocumentDefault -C 65535

ps.  DocTo calls VBA methods to achieve its aims.
